# Customization API for plugin development

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, customization

I would like to know, is it possible to use the API for plugins or are there other API's that have the same functionalities?

The API injects inline css or stylesheets?

I hope someone with experience can guide me.

Thanks.

Comment: By API - are you referring to filters and actions? or to wp api
?